# how to open another app(my own app) from Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two applications. customer app and vendor app. How to open vendor app from customer app **when click button**?

Is it possible to open another application from the Flutter app?

`com.demo.customer` and `com.demo.vendor`

I tried `url_launcher`. but It cannot give package name and open another application.

And also I tried this package,[device_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps) but not working for ios.

**Should be work on Android and ios.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a custom **url scheme** for the app you want to open.

You can read more here:

For iOS: [iOS Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app)

For Android: [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

There's also a nice plugin that can handle **deeplink** actions for Flutter.

[Flutter Uni Links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links)

When you have registered a custom url scheme (for example: demo://vendor) you can just call that url with **url_launcher** plugin:

```
launchUrl('demo://vendor')
```